# Change of view in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, backend

my swift code below presents two views what I have to do is display the SecondViewController. Swift when tapped on the login button, how can I do it by implementing it in the code below?
The code of the first view displays a login screen when clicking on the login button I must be push to SecondView.
I am new to swiftui

**SecondViewController.Swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct HomeView:  View {
    @State private var userTrackingMode: MapUserTrackingMode = .follow
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: 25.7617,
            longitude: 80.1918
        ),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(
            latitudeDelta: 10,
            longitudeDelta: 10
        )
    )

    var body: some View {
        Map(
            coordinateRegion: $region,
            interactionModes: MapInteractionModes.all,
            showsUserLocation: true,
            userTrackingMode: $userTrackingMode
        )
        
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

**MainView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            
            LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [Color("Color"),Color("Color1"),Color("Color2")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            if UIScreen.main.bounds.height > 800{
                
                Home()
            }
            else{
                
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    
                    Home()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Home : View {
    
    @State var index = 0
    @State var showingDetail = false
    @State var isModal: Bool = false
    
    
    
    func login(){
    
    }
    
    var body : some View{
        
        VStack{
            
            Image("logo")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 180)
            
            HStack{
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                    withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.8, dampingFraction: 0.5, blendDuration: 0.5)){
                     
                       self.index = 0
                    }
                    
                    
                }) {
                    
                    Text("Login")
                        .foregroundColor(self.index == 0 ? .black : .white)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50) / 2).sheet(isPresented: $isModal, content: {
                            
                        })
                    
                }.background(self.index == 0 ? Color.white : Color.clear)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                
                Button(action: {
                   withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.8, dampingFraction: 0.5, blendDuration: 0.5)){
                       
                      self.index = 1
                   }
                    
                }) {
                    
                    Text("New User")
                        .foregroundColor(self.index == 1 ? .black : .white)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50) / 2)
                    
                }.background(self.index == 1 ? Color.white : Color.clear)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                
            }.background(Color.black.opacity(0.1))
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            .padding(.top, 25)
            
            if self.index == 0{
                
                Login(mail: "", pass: "", areYouGoingToSecondView: false)
                
            }
            else{
                
                SignUp()
            }
            
            if self.index == 0{
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    
                    Text("Forget Password?")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                
                }
                .padding(.top, 20)
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct Login : View {
    
    @State var mail = ""
    @State var pass = ""
    @State var areYouGoingToSecondView: Bool=false
    
    var body : some View{
        
        VStack{
            
            VStack{
                
                HStack(spacing: 15){
                    
                    Image(systemName: "envelope")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                    TextField("Enter Email Address", text: self.$mail)
                    
                }.padding(.vertical, 20)
                
                Divider()
                
                HStack(spacing: 15){
                    
                    Image(systemName: "lock")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 15, height: 18)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                    SecureField("Password", text: self.$pass)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }) {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "eye")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    
                }.padding(.vertical, 20)
                
            }
            .padding(.vertical)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .padding(.bottom, 40)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding(.top, 25)
            
    
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Prova di stampa")
            }) {
          
                Text("LOGIN")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100)
                
                
            }.background(
            
                LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [Color("Color2"),Color("Color1"),Color("Color")]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
            )
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .offset(y: -40)
            .padding(.bottom, -40)
            .shadow(radius: 15)
        }
    }
}

struct SignUp : View {
    
    @State var mail = ""
    @State var pass = ""
    @State var checkpass = ""
    @State var repass = ""
    @State var name = ""
    @State var surname = ""
    
    var body : some View{
        
        VStack{
            
            VStack{
                
                HStack(spacing: 15){
                    
                    Image(systemName: "envelope")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                    TextField("Enter Email Address", text: self.$mail)
                    
                }.padding(.vertical, 20)
                
                Divider()
                
                HStack(spacing: 15){
                    
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 15, height: 18)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                    TextField("Enter Name", text: self.$name)
                    
            
                    
                }.padding(.vertical, 20)
                
                
                Divider()
                
                HStack(spacing: 15){
                    
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 15, height: 18)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                    TextField("Enter Surname", text: self.$surname)
                    
            
                    
                }.padding(.vertical, 20)
                
                
                
                HStack(spacing: 15){
                    
                    Image(systemName: "lock")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 15, height: 18)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                    SecureField("Password", text: self.$pass)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }) {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "eye")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    
                }.padding(.vertical, 20)
                
                Divider()
                HStack(spacing: 15){
                    
                    Image(systemName: "lock")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 15, height: 18)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                    SecureField("Re-Enter Password", text: self.$checkpass)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }) {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "eye")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    
                }.padding(.vertical, 20)
                
              
            }
            .padding(.vertical)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .padding(.bottom, 40)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding(.top, 25)
            
            
            
            //Button for signup user
            Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                
                Text("SIGNUP")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100)
                
            }.background(
            
                LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [Color("Color2"),Color("Color1"),Color("Color")]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
            )
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .offset(y: -40)
            .padding(.bottom, -40)
            .shadow(radius: 15)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two main ways to do this, as I understand, are:

1. use a `NavigationView` to wrap your `Home()` content, then use `NavigationLink` to replace one view with another (I am trying `NavigationStackView` from [this library](https://github.com/indieSoftware/NavigationStack), which works similarly)
2. use a `@State` variable in your `ContentView` class, and change it on successful login. You can use an `Int` index, or better yet, an `enum`:

```swift
enum MyViews {
    case home
    case secondView
    case someOtherView
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var viewToShow : MyViews
    var body: some View {
        
        if viewToShow == .home {
            ZStack{
            
                if UIScreen.main.bounds.height > 800{
                    Home()
                } else {
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                        Home()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if viewToShow == .secondView {
            HomeView()
        } else {
            Text("I'm not sure what to show you here")
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to decide how you want your Login button to report a change of state to its parent view, but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what John suggested, it might be worth creating an Observable class to use as an environment object so that many views can access and change the page. Something like:

```
enum Page {
case login
case home
case secondView
case someOtherView
}

class AppController: ObservableObject {
    
    // private(set) will mean you can only change pageControl
    // within this class (AppController) which will help prevent
    // bugs but remove if not necessary
    @Published private(set) var pageControl: Page
    @Published var isLoggedIn: Bool
    
    init() {
        self.pageControl = .login
        self.isLoggedIn = false
    }
    
    func someLoginFunction() {
        // will call self.changePage(.home) if login succeeds
        // and isLoggedIn to true
    }
    
    func changePage(_ page: Page) {
        self.pageControl = page
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
        var controller = AppController()
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                switch controller.pageControl {
                    case .login:
                        LoginView().environmentObject(controller)
                    case .home:
                        Home().environmentObject(controller)
                    default:
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

I used a switch statement instead of an If statement which does the same thing, just a bit neater :) The default in there is only needed at the moment because I haven't accounted for all the possibilities within the enum Page. Once you create cases for all the different pages, it shouldn't be needed!

In terms of the AppController, this could be your hub for controlling your app.  The @Published variables will update all the views that use them when it is updated (like @State). Sorry if I'm teaching fish to swim here, I just want to be thorough and you said you're new to swiftUI!

You will need to pass the AppController into every view you'd like to use it in like I have in the switch statement. Within the view you'd like to be able to use the AppController, you will need this line:

```
@EnvironmentObject var controller: AppController
```

And then you can access everything inside it by calling controller!

Any more questions, please let me know! Hope this helps.